# block a port so a process stop using it to connect

Tags: networking, iptables, firewall, ufw

I want to stop a process from connecting to a port, i have tried using ufw 
in the next example i am trying to deny connections to port 5100, and the process LEOCoin is listening to connections on that port

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     DENY        Anywhere
5100/udp                   DENY        Anywhere
5100/tcp                   DENY        Anywhere
22/tcp (v6)                DENY        Anywhere (v6)
5100/udp (v6)              DENY        Anywhere (v6)
5100/tcp (v6)              DENY        Anywhere (v6)

22/tcp                     ALLOW OUT   Anywhere
5100/tcp                   ALLOW OUT   Anywhere
5100/udp                   DENY OUT    Anywhere
8338                       ALLOW OUT   Anywhere
8338/tcp                   ALLOW OUT   Anywhere
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)
5100/tcp (v6)              ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)
5100/udp (v6)              DENY OUT    Anywhere (v6)
8338 (v6)                  ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)
8338/tcp (v6)              ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)
```

but i haven't been able to stop the process from connecting.
I also tried iptable, but didn't have any luck

Comment: Please [edit] your question to specify what port exactly you're trying to disable connections on, and what process exactly is connecting to it.

Comment: Please also post your current configurations of ufw and iptables.

Comment: `UFW` uses iptables...

Comment: looks like i was able to fix it myself, i needed to deny all out ports, and just allow the one i was gonna use, that work for me, thanks everybody who try to help me

Comment: Rather than block the port, fix whatever application is bound to port 5100 and accepting the connection. Or simply stop, uninstall, or change the settings on that application.